# pandas - Making a pivot table with MultiIndex columns

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following dataframe:

```
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('datetime', 'yearmonth'), ('datetime', 'month'),
     ('quantity', 'Q1'),('quantity', 'Q2'),('price','P1'),('price','P2'), ('cost', 'C1')])

data = [[201601,1,47,21,13,54,23],[201601,1,35,53,61,33,33],[201602,2,55,11,25,54,31],
        [201602,2,12,13,32,34,21],[201603,3,61,44,25,32,12],[201603,3,41,12,56,23,12]]

rng = ['1/1/2016','1/5/2016','2/1/2016','2/23/2016','3/5/2016','3/7/2016']
index = pd.to_datetime(rng)

df = pd.DataFrame(data,index=index, columns=columns)

            datetime       quantity     price     cost
           yearmonth month       Q1  Q2    P1  P2   C1
2016-01-01    201601     1       47  21    13  54   23
2016-01-05    201601     1       35  53    61  33   33
2016-02-01    201602     2       55  11    25  54   31
2016-02-23    201602     2       12  13    32  34   21
2016-03-05    201603     3       61  44    25  32   12
2016-03-07    201603     3       41  12    56  23   12
```

I'm trying to create a pivot table that summarizes the data by the `yearmonth` column(gets the sum and average - 2 different dfs). Ultimately it should look something like this:

```
             yearmonth   201601  201602  201603
cost     C1                56      52      24
price    P1                74      57      81
         P2                87      88      55
quantity Q1                82      67     102
         Q2                74      24      56
```

I tried `pd.pivot_table(df,columns=('datetime','yearmonth'))` but I got the following error: `KeyError: 'yearmonth'`

How do I create a pivot table when the columns are MultiIndexed?